# How to avoid Errors in try with several instructions?

Tags: python

I encounter a problem with this code :

```py
def stupid_function():
    try:
        stupid_instruction1()
        stupid_instruction2()
    except:
        pass
```

When it see an error in `stupid_instruction1()`, it doesn't even try to run `stupid_instruction2()`. Is there any way that it do it ? (Thanks)

Comment: Errors go directly to error handlers. Why not have `stupid_instruction2()` in its own `try` block? Alternatively -- put it in a `finally` clause if you are confident that it won't error out.

Comment: Side-note: Bare (unqualified) excepts, `except:`, are a *terrible* idea. You'll catch `SystemExit`, `KeyboardInterrupt` and other exceptions that are never supposed to be caught unless you're expecting them specifically, or are simply catching them long enough to log an error and re-`raise`. If nothing else, limit the clause to `except Exception:` which is still overbroad, but at least it doesn't catch errors that have no business being caught in the general case.

Comment: In most programs, "on error, keep going anyway" is not the ideal design. Suppose you told your robot assistant `get_glass(); pour_milk();`. if the first function raises a NoGlassFoundException, you would prefer the task to halt completely, rather than keep going and pour milk all over your kitchen.

Comment: [This is a pretty good example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4yH4B9deok) of what happens when you do that...

Comment: @Kevin o, then you'd be left with no choice but to cry over spilt milk.

Comment: @Kevin, the problem is that I WANT to pour milk all over my kitchen

Comment: @Atzelord Then, don't bother getting the glass at all, and procede to flood the appartment :)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier But then I won't know if I can get a glass. I need to try the 2 instructions separatly, but I would like to do it in a better way than precised in Luke Ning's answer. If there is absolutely no other ways, I'll do like he suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the 2 functions in two different try blocks:

```
def stupid_function():
    try:
        stupid_instruction1()
    except:
        pass
    try:
        stupid_instruction2()
    except:
        pass
```

With the caveat being that you shouldn't actually be excepting every error and should only be excepting specific errors.

Comment: It is exactly what I would like to avoid, because with a lot of instructions it tooks dozens of lines

Answer (score 0):

Does `stupid_instruction2()` need to be in a try catch?
If it does then I would recommend putting the `try/catch` inside the function you are calling (if it is your own function).  If it is not your own function then wrap it like this:

```
def my_stupid_instruction2():
    try:
        stupid_instruction2()
    except:
         pass
```

If you want `stupid_instruction2()` to be called no matter what than you can do it like this.

**Example:**

```
def stupid_function():
    try:
        stupid_instruction1()
    except: # As Luke pointed out, it is bad practice to do a general exception
        pass
    finally:
        stupid_instruction2() # This will be run regardless if the try fails
```